# Sync Gradle always stops with error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

For backward compatibility problem, I need com.google.android:support-v4:r13, but Sync Gradle always comes up with an error:

```
Error:Could not find com.google.android:support-v4:r13.
Required by:GA:app:unspecified
GA:app:unspecified > com.fizz-buzz:fb-android-dagger:1.0.3
```

I have in dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile files('libs/support-v4-r13.jar')
compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r13'
```

and I even have it my libs folder
[image]

I did an 'Add as library' on it, cleaned the project, but nothing works.
What am I doing wrong?

Maybe this gives an additional indication. When I do Rebuild, I get this:
[image]

Comment: try removing this line compile files('libs/support-v4-r13.jar') from dependencies in gradle file and delete the jar file also and then try to sync

Comment: did that. Unchanged!

Comment: ok now remove all and add the support library using gui i.e. go to file > project struction > YourProject > dependencies click on the plus sign and select add library dependency and type there support-v4 and search it will give you the latest support library

Comment: Did this now, even Invalidated all caches. I can see it in the Project Structure taht it was added, but Sync still comes up with the same error message

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### Your Dependencies:

```
dependencies { 
    compile files('libs/support-v4-r13.jar')  // <-- try not use jars
    compile 'com.google.android:support-v4:r13' // <-- does not exist
}
```

The library that does not exist(see versions and dates): http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android/support-v4

### Should be:

```
dependencies {
    com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.1 // <-- gradle dependency
}
```

Always refer to the docs: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v4