# Android Studio: cannot upgrade google play services

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

I have tried download the latest version on the sdk manager, but is still not working.  I have seen [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25757749/5016464) telling users to enter the following...

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'
```

I do not understand where to enter it. I tried in the terminal feature of the android studio but it gives me a bash "command not found" error.

if it matters I am trying to implement the example maps that android studio gives you when you begin a new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Android Studio` open the `build.gradle` file and enter inside `dependencies`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.+'
}
```

more info [**Add Google Play Services to Your Project**](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: Please do not suggest this. You need to use the "modules". This dependency alone is gigantic. Also, the current version is `7.5.0`.

Comment: write to google to stop doing this https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup , and btw why do you suggest this ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30124661/sync-gradle-always-stops-with-error/30127666#30127666

Comment: To stop doing what? They are using `7.5.0` in that link you just posted. Suggest what? That user was bringing in duplicate jars. It is best to use gradle dependencies vs jars as well.

Comment: Note: as of [Google Play services 6.5](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/11/google-play-services-65.html), you should *always* use [selective APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) to only include the parts of Google Play services you need.